# Which SQL would run faster in SQL Server to convert column type and calculate the average value？

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I have a big table now(2 billion rows) in SQL Server and I want to calculate the average value of some columns. For example, a column named

```
Speed (VARCHAR)
```

I need to change the type of Speed first and then use AVG(Speed). I designed several SQL for this:

```
update dbo.xxx 
set Speed = convert(int, Speed)

select avg(Speed) as avg_Speed 
from dbo.xxx
```

or:

```
alter table dbo.xxx 
    alter column Speed int

select avg(Speed) as avg_Speed 
from dbo.xxx
```

or:

```
select avg(cast(Speed as int)) as avg_Speed 
from dbo.xxx
```

Which one would be faster?

Add: my goal is to save these average value in a new table

Comment: Please paste the full sql

Comment: If you need this information frequently then it is better (2nd option) to convert the column data type first then use Aggregation function without a need for type cast. But if this is a task which will be done only once, you can continue with the 3rd option

Comment: On top of what @Eralper has said, I would recommend validating data first to avoid "Conversion failed" errors. You can do basic validation using [`ISNUMERIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) function